# Group and aggregate the data based on categorical variables in R

Tags: r, data.table

Consider the following data table

```
data.table(col1 = rep(LETTERS[1:3],3), col2 = rep(LETTERS[7:9],3), col3 = 1:9)

   col1 col2 col3
1:    A    G   1
2:    B    H   2
3:    C    I   3
4:    A    G   4
5:    B    H   5
6:    C    I   6
7:    A    G   7
8:    B    H   8
9:    C    I   9
```

Here col1 and col2 are categorical variables. Now do do I group the data such as below

```
   col1 col2 col3
1:    A    G   [1, 4, 7]
2:    B    H   [2, 5, 8]
3:    C    I   [3, 6, 9]
```

Basically here I can use `group by` to get combinations but I guess it wont give me the col3 as required. It can be done by writing two `for` loops, but consider a situation when there are higher number of these kind of variables. Can this be done without going for the `for` loops.

Comment: Try `dt[, .(col3 = toString(col3)), .(col1, col2)]` as a string or store as a `list` i.e. `dt[, .(col3 = list(col3)), .(col1, col2)]`

Comment: @akrun Ok Thank you very much. That works!

Comment: @akrun Can i reverse the process, that is, can i get back the original table from the resultant table?